# for which variables in panel data i should do stationary test?

Tags: panel-data, stationarity, qualitative

i have a panel data and my dependent variable was stationary according to ADF test.now i dont know should i test it for my independent variables too or not?
btw does it make sense to take stationary tests from qualitative variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the panel doesn't include many years (not a long panel), you don't need to do that test.